# T-SQL MERGE statement - ... WHEN MATCHED AND ... OR ... - are brackets (parentheses) required?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

In the following subsection of a t-SQL MERGE statement, are the brackets (parentheses) required?

```
  WHEN MATCHED  
           AND (  Target.CustomerName <> Source.CustomerName 
               OR Target.Planet <> Source.Planet
               )
  THEN
  UPDATE SET
        Target.CustomerName = Source.CustomerName
      , Target.Planet = Source.Planet
```

I ask because I'm using a t-SQL formatting tool (ApexSQL), which identifies these brackets as unnecessary, and so removes them, thus:

```
  WHEN MATCHED  
           AND Target.CustomerName <> Source.CustomerName 
           OR  Target.Planet <> Source.Planet

  THEN
  UPDATE SET
        Target.CustomerName = Source.CustomerName
      , Target.Planet = Source.Planet
```

However, this jars with my fundamental understanding of AND, OR logic... Is this a special case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its optional however, when ur mixing AND and OR, always use () for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is optional. the sintax to use `WHEN MATCHED`

```
WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
```

the `clause_search_condition` is evaluated separately